# Portable flash without a camera?

Tags: flash

I’m organising a “fake paparazzi” scene with a few friends as part of a fancy dress party.

I don’t want to take a camera, I only need the flash for the effect. The flash must be portable.

I’ve had a search on google but I can’t find any suitable products. Do standard TTL flashes work/can be triggered without a camera?

Comment: "I only need the flash for the effect." – Are you not taking any photos at all with the flash?

Comment: vtc b/c "I don’t want to take a camera" – It seems you have no photographic intent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no photographic intent or application of this question.

Answer (score 5):

Speedlight flashes for cameras typically have a Test button on them that will flash it anytime.  If the flash menu is set to TTL mode, it probably flashes at moderate power level. If set to Manual mode, and highest power level 1:1 is selected, it flashes at that level.

Since questions are supposed to be about taking pictures, it may make a better party effect to have a friend with appropriate camera actually taking pictures. Some guests may want a copy of those pictures.

Comment: Seems like a good opportunity for OP to use any of the new Polaroid cameras (impossible project/lomo/etc) to get some instant paparazzi images for people

Comment: Do mind that a big speedlite, even more the "hammerhead" form factor, on manual mode can be painfully or even unsafely bright if set off straight in someone's face.